# fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.distribute.distribution_strategy_context'

Tags: tensorflow

this problem in jupyter couldn't be fixed even after uninstall and reinstallation of tensorflow package.

I have imported tensorflow in the very first cell of my code and it didn't work with this kind of error. here is the list of imports about this package:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing
import image from tensorflow.keras.layers
import LSTM from tensorflow.keras.layers
import BatchNormalization
```

Comment: There's an abundance of related posts and information on this. Additionally how you specifically installed is not described? So it becomes hard to advise what to do with specifics. Help those trying to help you. Please in the future read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You'll see the second paragraph asks about research. What other research have you tried? Nothing is noted here. Then next pay close attention to the section entitled 'Help others reproduce the problem'. That would get at telling us specifically how you are installing it ...

Comment: <continued> and start getting at what error you are seeing **with a full traceback included as text code in your future posts**. That all aside, I suspect you aren't understanding how to install so that Jupyter sees what you are installing. (Again, I'm guess here based on your limited information supplied so understand this is all an assumption.) Jupyter runs in a very specific environment and you need to install things there or point Jupyter at where on your system you did install it already. The problem may be though that what you installed somewhere on your system may be meant to work ...

Comment: <continued> with Python elsewhere on your system and not the Python necessarily that Jupyter is using. To make this easier, in 2019 the modern magic commands were added that allow you to install most things from inside a cell running in your active Jupyter `.ipynb` file. If you use the magic version of the install commands it will conveniently install to the environment that Jupyter is using at the time. In a new cell in your current notebook, try running `%pip install tensorflow` and the restarting the kernel and trying to run your import statements. Hopefully that gets you beyond the ...

Comment: <continued> current hurdle. In other words, you may see a different error but that should be progress. Note this assumption you'll see a different error assumes the thing you don't have right now comes from that package but because you didn't include the full traceback in your post, I cannot be sure. Importantly, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic install commands. Even if they don't fix what you need here, they are what you should be using if you are installing from inside a notebook.